# getApplicationContext() returns null in Application's onCreate()

Tags: android

Okay, I'm at a loss with this problem, it doesn't quite make sense to me. In my app, my Application-class looks something like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    private static Context sContext;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sContext = getApplicationContext();
        SomeClass.someMethod(sContext.getString(R.string.some_string));
        [...]
    }
    [...]
}
```

The app itself runs a few Services. Now for some reason I get reports of users getting a NullPointerException for `sContext.getString(R.string.some_string)`. Not a lot, to be honest a very small amount of users, mostly on Android 4 and Samsung devices, and about 50% of the errors have the app running in the background, but still enough to get at least two people to complain. And I don't know how this could happen. I have no idea how this could happen for <1% of my users. Has anyone encountered something similiar or has an idea how `sContext` could be null at that point?

Comment: Make sure you have added `android:name=".MyApplication"` in your `application` tag of  manifest file

Comment: `sContext = this;` and no, you dont need `sContext.getString(R.string.some_string)` just use `getString(R.string.some_string)`

Comment: @NileshRathod It is added there, and if it wasn't this would happen on every device I have this app running on.

Comment: @pskink That would probably fix this, yes, but my App may run into other problems as sContext is also used elsewhere (I know, static application context is bad code, I'm trying to fix it bit by bit). Shouldn't getApplicationContext() work at this point?

Comment: It may happens because differents api... so it doesn't mean that it's not good done, so give it a try with a device that is crashing

Comment: Also I don't get why you use static stuff could you post your full code to understand it?

Comment: `"Shouldn't getApplicationContext() work at this point?"` - i dont know, try to set a breakpoint and check if 
 it goes here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#303

Comment: @pskink it does.

Comment: and what is returned? `mPackageInfo.getApplication()` or `mMainThread.getApplication()`?

Comment: `mPackageInfo` is not null, so the first one.

Comment: so check why `mApplication` is null [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/LoadedApk.java#151)

Comment: Sadly I can't replicate the error here, I only got StackTraces from Users.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have this in your `manifest.xml`

```
<application android:name="packagename.MyApplication"/>
```

The problem is on this lane I guess:

```
SomeClass.someMethod(sContext.getString(R.string.some_string));
```

So, you can do it using `getResources().getString()...` or just `getString(R.string.some_string)` instead of `sContext.getString(...)`

Comment: Good guess, but as you can see in the comments I've already checked that. Your solution will fix the error at this point but sContext is used elsewhere, too and with it bein null other problems may arise.

Comment: Can you post your full code please? To see why are you using static?

Comment: I can't post the full code, no, because that may get competition to rip off our code. What I can say is that the static context is used in many places to get things like the WifiManager, Time-Pattern-Strings, etc. Keeping a context in those places is not feasable as those classes are usually singletons (so for each getInstance()-call you would've to supply a context just on the offchance that the singleton isn't initialized yet) or would've to pass a context through multiple classes and keep weak references in background tasks. This was the easiest path when the app was written. Fix is planned